# BluetoothServerSocket accept() not returning on HTC Desire

Tags: android-bluetooth, android

I'm working on a bluetooth-capable application, based on the well-known BluetoothChat example.
Basically with this app a client can send some packets to a server.

I have tested the application using two Xperia smartphones (Xperia X8 and Xperia Sola, android 2.1 and 4.0) and all is working fine: they both can act as client or server.

Unfortunately if I use an HTC Desire (android 2.3) as server, it won't be able to accept incoming connection from one of the Xperia client. It seems that the client `connect()` returns as if all was fine, but instead the server is blocked on its `accept()` as if nothing was happened.

Relevant code snippets:

**1. "Accept Thread"**

```
private class BluetoothAcceptThread extends Thread
    {
        private final BluetoothServerSocket serverSocket;

        public BluetoothAcceptThread()
        {
            BluetoothServerSocket tmpSocket = null;      

            try   
            {
                Method m = bluetoothAdapter.getClass().getMethod("listenUsingRfcommOn", new Class[] {int.class});
                tmpSocket = (BluetoothServerSocket) m.invoke(bluetoothAdapter, APP_BT_CHANNEL);
            }
            catch (NoSuchMethodException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (InvocationTargetException e)
            {
                Log.e(MainActivity.ERROR_TAG, "BluetoothAcceptThread listen() (with reflection) failed", e);
            }
            catch (IllegalAccessException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            serverSocket = tmpSocket;
            Log.d(MainActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "BluetoothAcceptThread ServerSocket created");
        }

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            BluetoothSocket socket = null;

            try
            {
                Log.d(MainActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "BluetoothAcceptThread calling accept()...");
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                Log.d(MainActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "BluetoothAcceptThread accept() returned");
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Log.e(MainActivity.ERROR_TAG, "BluetoothAcceptThread accept() failed: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            if (socket != null)
            {
                Log.d(MainActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "BluetoothAcceptThread accept() successfully");

                synchronized (BluetoothManager.this)
                {
                    if (currentState == SocketState.LISTENING || currentState == SocketState.CONNECTING)
                        startBluetoothConnection(socket);  // all is ok, it can proceed

                    else if (currentState == SocketState.INACTIVE || currentState == SocketState.CONNECTED)
                        cancel(socket);     
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void cancel()
        {
            try
            {
                serverSocket.close();
                Log.d(MainActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "BluetoothAcceptThread ServerSocket closed");
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Log.e(MainActivity.ERROR_TAG, "BluetoothAcceptThread close() failed", e);
            }
        }

        private void cancel(BluetoothSocket newSocket)
        {
            try
            {
                newSocket.close();
                Log.d(MainActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "BluetoothAcceptThread client socket closed");
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Log.e(MainActivity.ERROR_TAG, "BluetoothAcceptThread client socket close() failed", e);
            }
        }
    }
```

**2. "Connect thread"**

```
private class BluetoothConnectThread extends Thread
    {
        private final BluetoothSocket socket;
        private final BluetoothDevice device;

        public BluetoothConnectThread(BluetoothDevice d)
        {
            device = d;
            BluetoothSocket tmpSocket = null;  

            try   
            {
                Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});
                tmpSocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, APP_BT_CHANNEL);
            }
            catch (NoSuchMethodException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (InvocationTargetException e)
            {
                Log.e(MainActivity.ERROR_TAG, "BluetoothConnectThread create() (with reflection) failed", e);
            }
            catch (IllegalAccessException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            socket = tmpSocket;
            Log.d(MainActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "BluetoothConnectThread client socket created");
        }

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            stopBluetoothDiscovery();  // otherwise it will slow down the connection

            try
            {
                socket.connect();
                Log.d(MainActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "BluetoothConnectThread connect() successfully");
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Log.e(MainActivity.ERROR_TAG, "BluetoothConnectThread connect() failed", e);
                String deviceName = device != null ? device.getName() : "none";
                connectionFailed(deviceName);  // notify UI thread
                return;
            }

            synchronized (BluetoothManager.this)
            {
                bluetoothConnectThread = null;   
            }

            startBluetoothConnection(socket);  // create the "Communication" Thread
        }

        @Override
        public void cancel()
        {
            try
            {
                socket.close();
                Log.d(MainActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "BluetoothConnectThread client socket closed");
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Log.e(MainActivity.ERROR_TAG, "BluetoothConnectThread close() failed", e);
            }
        }
    }
```

**3. "Communication Thread"** (aka ConnectedThread in BluetoothChat sample)

```
private class BluetoothCommunicationThread extends Thread
    {
        private final BluetoothSocket socket;
        private final InputStream inputStream;
        private final OutputStream outputStream;

        public BluetoothCommunicationThread(BluetoothSocket s)
        {
            socket = s;
            InputStream in = null;
            OutputStream out = null;

            try
            {
                in = socket.getInputStream();
                out = socket.getOutputStream();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Log.e(MainActivity.ERROR_TAG, "BluetoothCommunicationThread failed to get streams", e);
            }

            inputStream = in;
            outputStream = out;
        }

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BT_BUFF_SIZE];
            int readBytes;    

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    readBytes = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

                    if (readBytes != -1)
                    {
                        Message message = messageHandler.obtainMessage(DATA_MSG, readBytes, -1, buffer);
                        message.sendToTarget();  // notify to UI thread the bytes counter
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        BluetoothDevice device = socket.getRemoteDevice();
                        String deviceName = device != null ? device.getName() : "none";
                        connectionLost(deviceName);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    Log.e(MainActivity.ERROR_TAG, "BluetoothCommunicationThread read() failed", e);
                    BluetoothDevice device = socket.getRemoteDevice();
                    String deviceName = device != null ? device.getName() : "none";
                    connectionLost(deviceName);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        public void write(byte[] buffer)
        {
            try
            {
                outputStream.write(buffer);
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Log.e(MainActivity.ERROR_TAG, "BluetoothCommunicationThread write() failed", e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void cancel()
        {
            try
            {
                socket.close();
                Log.d(MainActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "BluetoothCommunicationThread socket closed");
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Log.e(MainActivity.ERROR_TAG, "BluetoothCommunicationThread close() failed", e);
            }
        }
    }
```

So the steps of the problem are the following:

1. HTC Desire server calls `accept()`
2. Xperia client calls `connect()`
3. The `connect` returns as if the connection was established
4. Nothing is happening on the HTC, always blocked on `accept()`
5. Xperia client thinks that it's connected, so it creates the CommunicationThread and calls the blocking `read()`; this function throws `java.io.IOException: Software caused connection abort`, probably because the socket is not connected.

Finally these are the relevant logcats:

**Xperia client:**

```
09-20 00:44:23.562    9106-9106/com.powertester D/[PowerTester Debug]﹕ BluetoothConnectThread client socket created
09-20 00:44:25.704    9106-9579/com.powertester D/[PowerTester Debug]﹕ BluetoothConnectThread connect() successfully
09-20 00:44:25.734    9106-9579/com.powertester D/[PowerTester Debug]﹕ BluetoothCommunicationThread started and I/O streams ready
09-20 00:44:25.764    9106-9589/com.powertester E/[PowerTester Error]﹕ BluetoothCommunicationThread read() failed
        java.io.IOException: Software caused connection abort
        at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readNative(Native Method)
        at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.read(BluetoothSocket.java:333)
        at android.bluetooth.BluetoothInputStream.read(BluetoothInputStream.java:96)
        at com.powertester.net.BluetoothManager$BluetoothCommunicationThread.run(BluetoothManager.java:518)
09-20 00:44:25.844    9106-9106/com.powertester D/[PowerTester Debug]﹕ BluetoothCommunicationThread socket closed
```

**HTC server**:

```
09-19 15:47:07.591    2422-2422/com.powertester D/[PowerTester Debug]﹕ BluetoothAcceptThread ServerSocket created
09-19 15:47:07.591    2422-2484/com.powertester D/[PowerTester Debug]﹕ BluetoothAcceptThread calling accept()...
```

The *really* strange thing is that the HTC Desire *works* if used as client with one of the Xperia used as server.

So, is a problem of my app or a problem in the HTC Desire bluetooth stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some troubles I have realized that the problem is the reflection itself and the explicit use of a Bluetooth Channel.

Using the normal way (i.e. [the not-hidden bluetooth methods](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html)) my app works perfectly.